# Inserting a string in a SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

How can I store an `String` within my `SQLite` database?

```
 String et11 = et1.getText().toString();
 String et22 = et2.getText().toString();
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ZAKHIRE (USER , PAS) VALUES ( " + et11 + et22 +")");
 db.close();
```

Comment: where is `,`????. syntax problem.

Comment: As @IntelliJAmiya pointed out, you need a comma between `et11` and `et12` in your `db.execSQL` line. Otherwise it'll just put the two strings together and then your database will read them as one value.

Comment: Is this the right method used?  I encounter an error

Comment: Read [Saving Data Using SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html).

Comment: Even when  I use one String,  warns me

Answer (score 2):

#### In your Activity

```
 DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());  
 String  name = mName.getText().toString().trim();
 String  pass = mPasswd.getText().toString().trim();
 dbHelper.insertRecord(name, pass);
```

#### DbHelper class

*This is override method that extends SQLiteOpenHelper in DBhelper 
class.*

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + Name + " TEXT,"
                + Password + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

   void insertRecord(String name, String password) {
        dataBase = getWritableDatabase();
        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Name, name);
        values.put(Password, password); 
        Log.e("Values are ", String.valueOf(values));
        dataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        dataBase.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO ZAKHIRE (USER , PAS) VALUES`

Is saying **insert** a new row where columns **USER** and **PAS** are the **2** **VALUES** that are enclosed within the brackets that are separated from each other by a comma.

Assuming et11 has the value FRED and et22 has the value PASSWORD then `VALUES ( " + et11 + et22 +")"` equates to `VALUES (FREDPASSWORD)` i.e. just one value.

However, to insert a string the string  must be enclosed in in single quotes (numbers need not be enclosed in single quotes).

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two
>   single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the
>   backslash character are not supported because they are not standard
>   SQL.
>
> Extract from [SQL As Understood By SQLite - expression](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Using the above example you would need it to be **`VALUES ('FRED','PASSWORD')`**

So to fix this you need to **a)** separate the two values with a comma and **b)** enclose both strings in quotes.

So you could use :-

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ZAKHIRE (USER , PAS) VALUES( '" + et11 + "','" + et22 + ")");
```

- *Note! Ramesh R's answer (using the SQLiteDatabase `insert` method) is the preferable method; it basically builds the SQL, quoting strings and adding commas etc for you.*

Comment: Looks like perfect.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thks.